# how do we get an insight into return visitor behaviour in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, what do you do to get an insight into returning visitor behaviour?

By default, the page views report gives you a list of top 50 pages.
Is there a way to get the top 50 pages for return visitors only?

I'm trying to find out why do return visitors return to the site? 
What is it that make them come back?

Is it possible to find out what's the top page for the second visit for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where segments come in. With segments, you can create a 'view' of traffic that meets certain criteria.

You may already have a segment for "Returning Users" that has been created by default.